Downloading Sharepoint .aspx files via custom C# program - SSL Error
I am working on a university project. I have a c# program that should be able to download an ASPX file from Sharepoint. I am connecting to Sharepoint with a Cisco AnyConnect VPN. (CODE BELOW)
The problem is I keep Getting an SSL auth error. I am able to see the Sharepoint site in Postman and the Browser. I've tried a couple of methods to ignore the SSL cert, but nothing seems to work. (Please See Error Code Below)
using System;
using System.IO;
using System.Net; //required for the Service Point Manager
using System.Net.Http;
using System.Net.Http.Headers;
using System.Threading.Tasks;

namespace SharePointRESTCoreApp
{
    class Program
    {
        static async Task Main(string[] args)
        {
            //should bypass the ssl error
            ServicePointManager.ServerCertificateValidationCallback +=
                (sender, cert, chain, sslPolicyErrors) => true;
                
            string siteUrl = "URL";
            string libraryName = "Pages";
            string fileName = "Appointments.aspx";
            string userName = "username";
            string password = System.IO.File.ReadAllText("password.txt");

            // Log the start of the authentication process
            Console.WriteLine("Starting authentication...");

            var credentialCache = new CredentialCache();
            credentialCache.Add(new Uri(siteUrl), "NTLM", new NetworkCredential(userName, password));

            using (var httpClient = new HttpClient(new HttpClientHandler
            {
                Credentials = credentialCache
            }))
            {
                httpClient.DefaultRequestHeaders.Accept.Add(new MediaTypeWithQualityHeaderValue("application/json"));

                string apiUrl = $"{siteUrl}/_api/web/lists/GetByTitle('{libraryName}')/RootFolder/Files('{fileName}')/$value";

                // Log the API URL being requested
                Console.WriteLine($"Requesting API URL: {apiUrl}");

                HttpResponseMessage response = await httpClient.GetAsync(apiUrl);

                if (response.IsSuccessStatusCode)
                {
                    var filePath = Path.Combine(Directory.GetCurrentDirectory(), fileName);

                    using (var fileStream = await response.Content.ReadAsStreamAsync())
                    using (var outputStream = File.Create(filePath))
                    {
                        fileStream.CopyTo(outputStream);
                    }

                    Console.WriteLine($"File '{fileName}' downloaded successfully.");
                }
                else
                {
                    // Log the error status code and reason phrase
                    Console.WriteLine($"Error downloading file. Status code: {response.StatusCode}, Reason: {response.ReasonPhrase}");
                }
            }
        }
    }
}


Error Code:
Unhandled exception. System.Net.Http.HttpRequestException: The SSL connection could not be established, see inner exception.
 ---> System.Security.Authentication.AuthenticationException: The remote certificate is invalid because of errors in the certificate chain: NotTimeValid, PartialChain
   at System.Net.Security.SslStream.SendAuthResetSignal(ReadOnlySpan`1 alert, ExceptionDispatchInfo exception)
   at System.Net.Security.SslStream.CompleteHandshake(SslAuthenticationOptions sslAuthenticationOptions)
   at System.Net.Security.SslStream.ForceAuthenticationAsync[TIOAdapter](Boolean receiveFirst, Byte[] reAuthenticationData, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
   at System.Net.Http.ConnectHelper.EstablishSslConnectionAsync(SslClientAuthenticationOptions sslOptions, HttpRequestMessage request, Boolean async, Stream stream, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
   --- End of inner exception stack trace ---
   at System.Net.Http.ConnectHelper.EstablishSslConnectionAsync(SslClientAuthenticationOptions sslOptions, HttpRequestMessage request, Boolean async, Stream stream, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
   at System.Net.Http.HttpConnectionPool.ConnectAsync(HttpRequestMessage request, Boolean async, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
   at System.Net.Http.HttpConnectionPool.CreateHttp11ConnectionAsync(HttpRequestMessage request, Boolean async, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
   at System.Net.Http.HttpConnectionPool.AddHttp11ConnectionAsync(QueueItem queueItem)
   at System.Threading.Tasks.TaskCompletionSourceWithCancellation`1.WaitWithCancellationAsync(CancellationToken cancellationToken)
   at System.Net.Http.HttpConnectionPool.SendWithVersionDetectionAndRetryAsync(HttpRequestMessage request, Boolean async, Boolean doRequestAuth, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
   at System.Net.Http.AuthenticationHelper.SendWithAuthAsync(HttpRequestMessage request, Uri authUri, Boolean async, ICredentials credentials, Boolean preAuthenticate, Boolean isProxyAuth, Boolean doRequestAuth, HttpConnectionPool pool, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
   at System.Net.Http.RedirectHandler.SendAsync(HttpRequestMessage request, Boolean async, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
   at System.Net.Http.HttpClient.<SendAsync>g__Core|83_0(HttpRequestMessage request, HttpCompletionOption completionOption, CancellationTokenSource cts, Boolean disposeCts, CancellationTokenSource pendingRequestsCts, CancellationToken originalCancellationToken)
   at SharePointRESTCoreApp.Program.Main(String[] args) in /home/mbg/Downloads/test/dotnetcore/Program.cs:line 42
   at SharePointRESTCoreApp.Program.<Main>(String[] args)

I tried both
            //should bypass the ssl error
            ServicePointManager.ServerCertificateValidationCallback +=
                (sender, cert, chain, sslPolicyErrors) => true;

and
handler.ServerCertificateCustomValidationCallback = HttpClientHandler.DangerousAcceptAnyServerCertificateValidator;

As suggested on other  StackOverflow questions. I am still a student, please be kind! :)
eventual goal of the program is to parse the aspx file and place contents into a blazor component.
